# Algebraic equation for increasing cost

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been a bit stumped on how to write an equation on increasing costs and I'm wondering how I'd go about it. Any help is very much appreciated.

> Say I'm a real estate speculator.
>
> $X$ = How many houses I own
>
> $Y$ = How many houses I want to own
>
> $Z$ = Total cost
>
> (1st part) In America I want to buy houses. The cost of houses in America are $ \$ 1000$ each.

The equation for the above would be $(Y-X)⋅1000=Z$ e.g. If I want to own $5$ houses and currently own $3$ it's going to cost me $(5-3)⋅1000=\bf2000$, easy. Although the second part is not so easy for me.

> (2nd part) In Europe the cost of houses are $1000$ plus a $500$ tax per house I already own e.g. my 1st home purchase costs me $1000$, 2nd $1500$, 3rd $2000$, 4th $3500$ etc.

If I currently owned $0$ houses and wanted to own $10$ how would I write an equation to figure out the total cost?

As a followup question if I currently owned $4$ houses and wanted to own $7$ could I use the same equation to figure out the total cost?

Thank you very much for reading =)

Comment: For Europe, you can use this formula $(Y-X)\cdot 1000+500\cdot X=1000\cdot Y -500 \cdot X$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you own $X$ houses already and call $P_1$ the price of the first house you buy, $P_2$ the price of the second house you buy ...

\begin{eqnarray}
P_1 &=& 1000 + 500 X \\
P_2 &=& 1000 + 500 (X+1)\\
&\vdots& \\
P_n &=& 1000 + 500(X + n - 1)
\end{eqnarray}

That is, the price of the $n$-th house you buy will be

$$
P_n = 1000 + 500(X-1) + 500 n \tag{1}
$$

The total cost of buying $Y-X$ is just

\begin{eqnarray}
T &=& P_1 + \cdots + P_{Y-X} \\
&=& [1000 + 500(X-1)](Y-X) + 500 \color{red}{[1 + 2 + \cdots + (Y-X)]} \\
&=& [1000 + 500(X-1)](Y-X) + 500 \color{red}{\frac{(Y-X)(Y-X + 1)}{2}} \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Where I've used

$$
1 + 2 + \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \tag{3}
$$